# List of SET/MULTISET tables in Teradata

Tags: teradata, ddl

I need to figure out below question:

1. List of all SET and MULTISET tables
2. List of all SET and MULTISET tables:
   There is no inforamtion available in Teradata DBC tables where this information is clearly available. DBC.Tables has a column checkopt but it also does not gurantee that the table is SET or MULTISET.

Other alternative is, to get the REQUESTTEXT column and apply wild card operator to check if the table is SET or MULTISET. But in this column, all tables DDLs are not available, some table has alter table statements, create index statements and few has Create table statements with tablekind='T'

Kindly suggest any other way

Comment: You can use SHOW TABLE to "reverse engineer" DDL from the table header + dictionary info.

Comment: DBC.TablesV CHECKOPT=Y means the table potentially can have duplicate rows, i.e. is MULTISET with no unique index / constraint. For CHECKOPT=N if there is no unique index (UniqueFlag=Y in DBC.IndicesV) then it must be a SET table. For CHECKOPT=N that does have a unique index you would have to use SHOW TABLE.

Comment: I have checked by joining tablesv and indicesv with CHECKOPT='N' AND uniqueflag='y' but still the ratio is 50 50. Also in tablesv requesttext column, all table's does not have create table statements, some as alter statements as well. This is also causing issues in identifying SET and MULTISET tables

Comment: @KeenLearner - this is why Fred is saying you have to use the output from show table.  The requesttext column in Tablesv is just the most recent DDL executed on that table.  There is really no practical way to do what you want with pure SQL.

Comment: Yes you are right. Only drawback is to have only recent DDL is available in tablesv. Most of them does not contain create table statements

Answer (score 0):

The only good way is to do SHOW TABLE, export to a single file, and grep or find 'CREATE SET TABLE ' in the output.  For example.

```
SELECT 'SHOW TABLE '||
databasename||'.'||tablename||  ';'
from dbc.tablesv where
databasename = 'DB_CORE_T'
and tablekind = 'T'
order by databasename, tablename;
```